# How to remove the Sub category product URL Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

Default URL

```
http:// mystore.com/parent-category/child-category/product
```

I want to remove anything between parent-category and product so my urls look like:

```
http:// mystore.com/parent-category/product
```

I am pretty sure that setting up urls like this does not cause problems, because I can manually type the shortened url into an address bar and it goes to the same place as the longer one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always use the plugin  "premmerce permalink manager for woocommerce". You can completely customize the link structure of products and categories. Hope it helps!